# Dual-Boot with Vista?

Tags: windows-vista

I want to know how to dual boot my computer with ubuntu 12.04 and windows vista(step by step would be best) and also wanted to know if it would slow down my pc even more than it already is?

Comment: Installing Ubuntu alongside Windows Vista won't affect the performance of Vista in any way.

Answer (score 1):

1. You first install Vista, as you have done it until now.
2. You then free up some space with your partition manager. ([This](http://www.partition-tool.com/) is what I use, it is free.)
3. You create a bootable Ubuntu USB or CD (details on how to do that on Ubuntu page).
4. You install Ubuntu with the option "Install along side Windows."

Comment: As an alternative to "Partition Tool," you can use Vista's built-in Disk Management utility (`diskmgmt.msc`), which supports resizing NTFS partitions (and will schedule dynamic resizing operations on mounted partitions for shutdown, so they can be performed safely). Or use GParted on the Ubuntu CD. Or just run Ubuntu's installer on the CD, and tell it to install Ubuntu **alongside** other operating systems (it will dynamically shrink the Windows partitions for you, if no unpartitoned space currently exists). That is, most of the time, *all* you have to do is steps 3 and 4.