# How to install Ubuntu on a laptop alongside Windows Vista?

Tags: installation, dual-boot, partitioning

I have Windows vista 64 bit with a free `D:` drive that has nothing on it.

How do I install Ubuntu Dual Boot

The drive is formatted but did I do it right? How can I tell?

Comment: Why a lot of people believe that the name of Ubuntu is 'ubunto'?

Comment: You mention a free drive `d:\`, do you want to install Ubuntu in that drive or side by side with Windows Vista in `C:\`?

Comment: @StefK *with a dual boot up screen* **Alongside.**

Comment: This [answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/172100/12218) has a summary of the needed steps. At the end you will have a dual boot system and the boot manager (Grub) will ask you at every boot which Operating System to boot.

Answer (score 0):

You should install your Windows Vista. Next you should run Ubuntu form disc or pendrive and just install it. During the installation you will have check box "Instal next to Windows Vista".

And that is pretty all you need to do :)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't quite understand what is the exact problem you are facing while installing. Using the Windows installer is probably the easiest way to install Ubuntu alongside Windows. You can get started with the instructions given [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-with-windows). It will only work with 12.04 though.